# How do I disable time Period on UIDatePicker?

Tags: objective-c, uidatepicker, nsdatecomponents

I am working on an app that involves gathering components of 2 UIDatePickers, one for time and one for the date. I would love to if possible remove the Period column (AM/PM) from the time picker. If this is not possible, I still have not been able to find out which NSDateComponent or other variable represents the Period for retrieving it in code.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Consider changing the locale but also consider using the locale set by the user rather than forcing your choice on them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be able to set the `locale` property to remove AM/PM, but this will inconvenience users in other locales as @Wain points out in the comments.  Also, I think the only locales that don't show this will show 24-hour time instead (I could be wrong about that.)

For more comprehensive customization, you may wish to make your own **UIPickerView** instead of **UIDatePicker**.  The [docs are here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipickerview).